# Set operations on list of sets in R using sets package

Tags: r, set, set-operations

I am using [`sets` package in R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/relations/versions/0.2-0/topics/set). Now, i have a list of sets and I want to perform set operations on the list without having to loop. Like, I can do `set_intersection` with a variable number of arguments

```
set_intersection(set(1,2), set(2,3), set(4,5), set(5,6)..)
```

But what if I have a list like

```
ls = list(set(1,2), set(2,3), set(4,5), set(5,6))
```

How do I take intersection of all sets contained in `ls`? Tried to google it but can't find much.

Comment: Try `Reduce(set_intersection, ls)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `set_intersection`

```
library(sets)
Reduce(set_intersection, ls)
```

or with `do.call`

```
do.call(set_intersection, ls)
```

NOTE: It is better not to name objects with function names (`ls` is a function)